# Using Dell’s Goodix fingerprint driver for Ubuntu on Fedora 35

Tags: fedora, fingerprint

My Dell Inspiron laptop comes with a Goodix fingerprint sensor identified as ID 27c6:538c. It seems that this sensor doesn’t work out of the box, but Dell have a special repo with the drivers for Ubuntu.
I’m currently using Ubuntu 21.10, but would like to switch to Fedora.
I found [this site](https://aboutcher.co.uk/2020/10/goodix-fingerprint-reader-on-fedora-linux/) that explains how to install the Ubuntu driver but for a different Dell laptop and makes use of an Arch AUR package.
The driver itself is found in this site: [Index of /updates/dists/focal-somerville-melisa](http://dell.archive.canonical.com/updates/dists/focal-somerville-melisa/)

How can I install the driver for the fingerprint sensor from the Dell repo?

Comment: I don't know about Fedora, but those were the steps I did to install on Ubuntu. https://www.dell.com/community/Precision-Mobile-Workstations/Broadcom-58200-fingerprint-sensor-Linux-support-Precision-3541/m-p/8207735/highlight/true#M9660